# Remix erc20 contract totalsupply shows 0

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, erc-20

I create this contract using Remix.

When I call to totalsupply,it shows 0.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if your contract is deployed properly. You can also try to debug your tx.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code, rather than a screen shot.  Having the actual code makes your question show up in the search results more easily - a screenshot will impede that search.

Answer (score 1):

You have naming conflict here:

```
function totalSupply () public constant returns (uint totalSupply) {
    return totalSupply;
}
```

Statement `return totalSupply` refers to `returns (uint totalSupply)` rather than to `totalSupply` state variable.

BTW, simplest fix would be to remove this function completely, as `totalSupply` state variable is already declared as `public`, so no need to define explicit getter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the compiler version greater than 0.4.18 than replace the constant with view.

Comment: Please could you expand upon your answer, as it is rather short and, as it stands, would serve better as a comment? Maybe provide an example of the corrected code? See [How do I write a good answer?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)